# Moving solutions from 32bit XP to 64bit Win7 --> compile error

Tags: com, build, compilation, .net-framework-version

I developed some solutions (C#, VB.Net) with VS2008/VS2010 on a XP-computer (32bit). The solutions uses .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.5 and references to 32bit Com-objects (dll, exe). The solutions are compiled with build-setting release+x86. This worked fine.

Now I moved the solutions to a new computer with 64bit Windows7 and VS2010 Premium. Now I'm getting the following error when building the solutions.

This is the complete error message:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: IXDokService, Configuration: Release x86 ------
TlbImp : error TI0000: The input file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DSA\JetOffice Workflow\bin32\wrkflw32.exe' is not a valid type library.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1558,9): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "JetOfficeWorkflow".
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'IXDokServiceWebSetup' ------
ERROR: An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '80004005'
------ Pre-build validation for project 'IXDokServiceWebSetup' completed ------
------ Rebuild All started: Project: IXDokServiceWebSetup, Configuration: Release ------
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

wrkflw32.exe is a 32bit-exe (COM). When I'm changing the .NET Framework Version to 4 then the building process of the solution runs successfully.

But I don't want to change the .NET Framework version. Has someone an idea for me?

Comment: Post a complete error message.  Look in the Output window.